# How to detect Samsung Galaxy Note 9 (Android P) navigation bar whether it's VISIBLE or NOT

Tags: android, navigationbar, android-9.0-pie

I'm currently facing some problems on detection navigation bar on **Android Pie** (Note 9 device) whether it's **VISIBLE** or **NOT VISIBLE**. I have tried many many solutions on the internet such as: `KeyCharacterMap.deviceHasKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)` or `KeyCharacterMap.deviceHasKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)`. Even the `resources.getIdentifier("config_showNavigationBar", "bool", "android")` could not bring the result as i want. I just want to ask if there is any ways to detect the navigation bar on Android Pie. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can get navigation bar height to know it's visible or not visible by `Display.getRealMetrics(include navigation bar)`, 
`Display.getMetrics(not include navigation bar)`.